# Spring Why Interfaces instead Abstract Classes?

Tags: java, spring

Sometimes,we use Spring in some automatic way.
Today i was thinking and searching the followig.

Why we use to do this in Spring?
**@Autowired
IAnimal animal;**

And why we usually dont do something like this?
**@Autowired
Animal animal;**

Animal is an abstract class,and in our beans.xml ,or using @Autowired with Qualifier,we can specify which implementation we want.A Dog,a Cat,etc.

I know i am wrong,but i would like some explanation about the cons of the Abstract Class approach instead of Interfaces approach.

Now,if we want to inject some ORM implementation,Ibatis or Hibernate,it makes more sense to use interfaces injection,because both providers dot not share an abstract class,but they share same Interface.But any other example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In the early Spring versions, declaring an interface could be mandatory to make the bean working with some features that required proxy class generation via interface.
Recent Spring versions don't have any more this restriction. So now, in Spring (as without Spring) a shared good practice is to make a bean class implement an interface only if it makes sense : KISS (Keep it simple and stupid) principle.
Abstraction has a cost and we want to accept it only for good reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of an interface is multiple inheritance. Java does not allow you to extend multiple classes, and there are sensible reasons for this. Some languages allow this (e.g. C++ and others) and there are reasons why it can be useful, but Java doesn't.

However, you can implement multiple interfaces. There is also a more subtle point about what an interface really **is** vs. what a abstract class is.

If you have `class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass`, you are effectively saying "all instances of `MyClass` are instances of `MyAbstractClass`". This applies to most common metaphors applied to OOP. For example, all Dogs are in fact Animals.

However, an interface just defines some behaviour. In a lot of programming contexts, it makes more sense to define things by **what they can do**, rather than **what they are**. E.g. A Dog is a Barkable, Runnable, Walkable, Feedable, etc... Here you are defining what it can do.

With your Spring example, you probably don't care that the object you are working with is actually an Animal, you probably just care that it **can do all the things Animals** can do. That is a major reason why interfaces are preferred.

Comment: .I understand what you say,buy usually,we inject classes related to the "What they are" approach.In that example we are injecting an Animal,to use animal object inside our class.If we want to inject some ORM implementation,Ibatis or Hibernate,it makes more sense,because both providers dot not share an abstract class,but they share same Interface.But any other example?

Comment: Although not strictly @Autowired, the same principle can be applied to loggers, for example. You dont care about the logger object having a handle to the file, you don't care about FileOutputStream s, all you care about is that logger.info() does what you expect. You care about behvaiour.

Comment: Thats ok ,but it s not related to Spring and injection.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your project.

You want to use an interface (`IAnimal`) in cases where you may have multiple implementations of such interface and you are going to decide which one to use during packaging.

For example, let's say that implementations on `IAnimal` need to be different based on whether you are under Windows or Linux, during packaging you may want to prepare two different versions of your application (one for Windows and one for Linux) and each package will contain only the code meant for that platform.
In such case, in one package you will include the implementation for Windows and in the other case the implementation for Linux.

Another common scenario is teams working as "black boxes" with one team needing the dependency of another team. In that case all that is agreed between the teams is the "contract" of the implementation (that is: the interface). Your team will be able to work against a "mock" implementation built by you while the other team develops the one that will eventually be released.

Otherwise, the general advice is to "keep it simple" and add the interface only if it's demonstrated that it's needed. Not doing so will result in much more code than necessary, which will only make everybody's life difficult.

Comment: Thanks! One question,regarding the first example.Is not the same if i have several "childs" of the Animal Abstract class?And during package i choose DogWindows or DogLinux?

Comment: You can indeed use an abstract class as well. You probably want to avoid the abstract class however as it will force these alternative implementations to inherit from your abstract class, preventing whoever wrote them from inheriting from their own classes. This is acceptable when all the code lives in the same package anyway (you manage the release through configuration) but in general it's still preferable to use interfaces instead.

Comment: Well,i understand you are preventing to extend from other classs,but at the end DogWindows,should be a Dog.
You could do DogWindows extends OperatingSystemDogs (Extending from your own class) .But OperatingSystemDogs at the extends from Dogs.

Doing that interfaces,i will have a IAnimal ,and some implementation call DogWindows implements IAnimal
DogLinux implements IAnimal,
But those Dogs are dogs so i could extend from Dog (Or extend from OperatingSystemDog),because maybe i have behavior in common,so i am adding an interface for extra complicate things i think.Thanks for this debate!